# No puedo insertar una celda con JavaScript (insertCell is not a function)

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero es que cuando haga click en una imagen me inserte en la tabla una nueva celda con unos datos.

El problema es que me dice que `insertCell` no es una función (en la consola de los navegadores) y no sé por qué, estoy haciéndolo como veo que el resto lo hace en sus ejemplos.

Dejo el código **JavaScript** que he estado haciendo.

```
<script>    
   function insertaEjercicio(nombreejercicio)
    {

      var dia = document.getElementById('dia').value;
      var diatempo = "tempo" + dia;

      var row = document.getElementById('tempoLUNES');
      var x = row.insertCell(-1);

      x.innerHTML = "New cell";
</script>
```

Y también dejo el **HTML** que resulta de hacer todas las consultas PHP que realizo en este módulo.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web AdGYMnistrator</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   html, body{
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     height:100%;
     overflow:hidden;
   }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web%20AdGYMnistrator_files/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web%20AdGYMnistrator_files/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web%20AdGYMnistrator_files/w3.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web%20AdGYMnistrator_files/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Web%20AdGYMnistrator_files/jquery-3.js"></script>
    <script>
      function cargarDiv(div,url)
        {
          $(div).load(url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--
  *************************
  *     AREA DE LOGIN     *
  *************************
  -->
  <div class="loginBox">
        <br>
        <form class="loginForm" action="" method="post">
            <p class="field">
                <input value="1234" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" type="text">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </p>
                <p class="field">
                <input name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" type="password">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
                <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
            </p>

                  </form>
      <br>

       </div>
    <!--
    *************************
    *     AREA DE NAVEG     *
    *************************
    -->
    <div class="navidiv">
      <ul class="naviarea">
        <li class="botonnav"><a class="botontexto" href="http://192.168.2.244/index.php">NOTICIAS</a></li>
        <li class="botonnav"><a class="botontexto" onclick='cargarDiv("#contenidoBox","actividades.php")'>ACTIVIDADES</a></li>
        <li class="botonnav"><a class="botontexto" onclick='cargarDiv("#contenidoBox","horarios.php")'>HORARIOS</a></li>
        <li class="botonnav"><a class="botontexto" onclick='cargarDiv("#contenidoBox","ejercicios.php")'>EJERCICIOS</a></li>
        <li class="botonnav"><a class="botontexto" onclick='cargarDiv("#contenidoBox","tablas_crear.php")'>TABLAS</a></li>
              </ul>
    </div>
    <!--
    *************************
    *     AREA CONTENIDO    *
    *************************
    -->
    <div id="contenidoBox" class="contenidoBox">
<script>
   //AQUÍ VA EL JS QUE PUSE MÁS ARRIBA, LO BORRO PARA NO PONERLO DOS VECES.
   //AQUÍ VA EL JS QUE PUSE MÁS ARRIBA, LO BORRO PARA NO PONERLO DOS VECES.
   //AQUÍ VA EL JS QUE PUSE MÁS ARRIBA, LO BORRO PARA NO PONERLO DOS VECES.
</script>

<div class="contenidoTablas">
  <div class="contenidoTablasTemporal">
      <table id="tablatempo" style="font-size:14px;" cellspacing="7px">
        <tbody><tr>
          <th id="tempoLUNES">LUNES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="tempoMARTES">MARTES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="tempoMIERCOLES">MIÉRCOLES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="tempoJUEVES">JUEVES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="tempoVIERNES">VIERNES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="tempoSABADO">SÁBADO</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="tempoDOMINGO">DOMINGO</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
      </tbody></table>

  </div>

  <div class="contenidoTablasCrear">
    <form action="cambiarpassword.php" method="post" name="cambiarpassword">
      <table>

        <tbody><tr><th colspan="2"> CREAR TABLA </th>

        </tr><tr>
          <td style="text-align:right;">
            Nombre:
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="nombre_tabla" id="nombre_tabla" required="true" type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:right;">
            Día:
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="dia" id="dia">
              <option selected="selected" value="LUNES">Lunes</option>
              <option value="MARTES">Martes</option>
              <option value="MIERCOLES">Miércoles</option>
              <option value="JUEVES">Jueves</option>
              <option value="VIERNES">Viernes</option>
              <option value="SABADO">Sábado</option>
              <option value="DOMINGO">Domingo</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:right;">
            Músculo:
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="musculo" id="musculo" onchange="seleccionaMusculo(value)">
              <option value="" disabled="true">
                          </option><option selected="selected" value="Biceps">Biceps</option>
                          <option value="Dorsales">Dorsales</option>
                        </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="contenidoTablasCrearAviso" colspan="2" style="font-size:10px;">
            Para insertar un ejercicio a la tabla simplemente haga click en su imagen.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input value="Crear tabla" onclick="CrearTabla()" type="button">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input value="Crear tabla e imprimir" onclick="ImprimirTabla()" type="button">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- <input type="hidden" value="" id="buffer" name="buffer"> -->

      </tbody></table>
    </form>
  </div>


  <div name="contenidoTablasListaEjercicioSeries" id="contenidoTablasListaEjercicioSeries">

  </div>


  <div name="contenidoTablasLista" id="contenidoTablasLista">
<div class="contenidoEjerciciosListaCuadros" id="3" onclick="insertaEjercicio('Curl con barra')">
  <a class="contenidoEjerciciosListaCuadrosNombre">Curl con barra<br></a>
  <img src="Web%20AdGYMnistrator_files/biceps_curl_barra.gif">
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

El error concreto que me da tanto Google Chrome como Mozilla Firefox es:

> ```
> TypeError: row.insertCell is not a function
> ```

Comment: Tu variable `row` no es una row (`tr`) si no un `th`

Comment: @lois6b Vaya despiste más tonto... Le puse el ID a los TH en lugar de a los TR ^^'. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: no es una respuesta, es un comentario xD  te ha servido? quizá deberia publicarlo como respuesta pues

Comment: @lois6b Sí que me ha servido, el problema estaba en que le puse el ID a los TH en vez de a los TR, ponlo como respuesta y te la confirmo xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu variable `row` no es una row (`tr`) si no un `th`.

Deberías cambiar los `id` a los `tr`.

ej:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
    var x = row.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML = "New cell";
}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="myRow">
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```